# Hibernate mapping mappedBy and @JoinColumn

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I am using spring mvc and hibernate with annotation,
I have following mapping in my module entity class

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="mp_mod_id")
private Set<ModulePermissionMpg> modulePermissionMpg;
//getter and setter
```

and my ModulePermissionsMpg entity class has

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private ModuleMst moduleMst;
```

using this config when I inserts a module with four permissions logs are as follows

```
Hibernate: insert into a_modules (mod_created_date, mod_icon, mod_modified_date, mod_name, mod_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=? where mp_id=?
```

Here 1st problem is , "moduleMst_mod_id" this extra column gets inserted with NULL.There is already a column named mp_mod_id which contains mod_id.

And 2nd problem is when I tries to update this table like deletes 2 permission and added 1 new permission in this module log is as follow

```
insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update a_modules set mod_created_date=?, mod_icon=?, mod_modified_date=?, mod_name=?, mod_status=? where mod_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set moduleMst_mod_id=?, mp_created_by=?, mp_created_date=?, mp_mod_id=?, mp_modified_date=?, mp_perm_id=?, mp_status=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set moduleMst_mod_id=?, mp_created_by=?, mp_created_date=?, mp_mod_id=?, mp_modified_date=?, mp_perm_id=?, mp_status=? where mp_id=?
Hibernate: update a_module_permissions set mp_mod_id=null where mp_mod_id=?

org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.remove(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1211)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.CollectionRemoveAction.execute(CollectionRemoveAction.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at com.imobdev.dao.ImderpDaoImpl.update(ImderpDaoImpl.java:136)
    at com.imobdev.service.ImderpServiceImpl.update(ImderpServiceImpl.java:79)
    at com.imobdev.controller.ErpController.updateModule(ErpController.java:384)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.imobdev.controller.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'mp_mod_id' cannot be null
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:931)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2941)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1623)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1715)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1268)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1455)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1440)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 54 more
```

And when I tries to use following configuration in my module entity class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="mp_mod_id", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 private Set<ModulePermissionMpg> modulePermissionMpg;
```

using this config when I inserts a module with four permissions logs are as follows

```
Hibernate: insert into a_modules (mod_created_date, mod_icon, mod_modified_date, mod_name, mod_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into a_module_permissions (moduleMst_mod_id, mp_created_by, mp_created_date, mp_mod_id, mp_modified_date, mp_perm_id, mp_status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

In this problem is mp_mod_id will be inserted 0. That is mapping table has no id of new inserted module in module table.

but when I tries to update as same as above it works perfect.

what is wrong here?!?

Edited : 
ModuleMst.java

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="mp_mod_id")
private Set<ModulePermissionMpg> modulePermissionMpg;
```

ModulePermissionMpg.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="mp_mod_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private ModuleMst moduleMst;
```

with this it works while insertion but for edit when I makes query to fetch permissions with that specific mod_id it gives following error

```
Hibernate: select moduleperm0_.mp_id as mp_id1_3_, moduleperm0_.mp_mod_id as mp_mod_i4_3_, moduleperm0_.mp_created_by as mp_creat2_3_, moduleperm0_.mp_created_date as mp_creat3_3_, moduleperm0_.mp_modified_date as mp_modif5_3_, moduleperm0_.mp_perm_id as mp_perm_6_3_, moduleperm0_.mp_status as mp_statu7_3_ from a_module_permissions moduleperm0_ where moduleperm0_.mp_status<>? and moduleperm0_.mp_mod_id=?
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.imobdev.hibernate.entity.ModuleMst_$$_javassist_9 cannot be cast to javassist.util.proxy.Proxy
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.getProxy(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:771)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4613)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1115)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:973)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:921)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:387)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1264)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:103)
    at com.imobdev.dao.ImderpDaoImpl.getOldPermissions(ImderpDaoImpl.java:659)
    at com.imobdev.service.ImderpServiceImpl.getOldPermissions(ImderpServiceImpl.java:183)
    at com.imobdev.controller.ErpController.updateModule(ErpController.java:354)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.imobdev.controller.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Edited : 
ModuleMst.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="moduleMst", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Set<ModulePermissionMpg> modulePermissionMpg;
```

ModulePermissionMpg.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="mp_mod_id")
private ModuleMst moduleMst;
```

After removing  insertable and updatable attributes there comes following error

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.imobdev.hibernate.entity.ModulePermissionMpg column: mp_mod_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at ...
....
```

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. See example 7.21 for how to map a bidirectional association: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#d5e5628

Comment: I tried that using mappedBy as shown in that example but it still inserts 0 vale in mapping table @JBNizet

Comment: No, you didn't try it as in the example. You don't have any JoinColumn specified on the ManyToOne annotation (as the documentation example shows), so Hibernate uses the default join column name instead of the one you want. And you're using a column name instead of the field name `moduleMst` as your `mappedBy` attribute value. Notice how the example uses `troop`: the name of the field in Soldier which constitutes the other side of the association.

Comment: I did that modifications you can see that in question. @JBNizet

Comment: No, you didn't. You have two JoinColumn annotations. And you didn't follow example 7.2.1. The JoinColumn must be on the ManyToOne only. Remove insertable and updatable attributes. And add the mappedBy attribute in the OneToMany, using the value `moduleMst`.

Comment: I tried this exactly as you are saying but when I removes insertable and updatable attributes is gives error  "Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.imobdev.hibernate.entity.ModulePermissionMpg column: mp_mod_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false") "

Comment: If you tried "exactly as I'm saying", then why do you still have two JoinColumn annotations in your code and no mappedBy attribute?

Comment: I was editing my question now you can see that @JBNizet

Comment: The message says that the column mp_mod_id is mapped more than once. So you probably have another field in the ModulePermissionMpg entity that is mapped to the same column. Remove that field.